# Visual studio Not run T4 after edit AddView List

Tags: templates, t4

I am edited T4 List.tt from this path:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML`

and when trying to Add view from here [Add View from controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMwdN.png)

this is old code:

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cshtml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Linq.Mapping" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.BuiltIn" #>
<#
MvcTextTemplateHost mvcHost = MvcTemplateHost;
#>
@model IEnumerable<#= "<" + mvcHost.ViewDataTypeName + ">" #>
<#
// The following chained if-statement outputs the file header code and markup for a partial view, a content page, or a regular view.
if(mvcHost.IsPartialView) {
#>

<#
} else if(mvcHost.IsContentPage) {
#>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "<#= mvcHost.ViewName#>";
<#
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mvcHost.MasterPageFile)) {
#>
    Layout = "<#= mvcHost.MasterPageFile#>";
<#
}
#>
}

<h2><#= mvcHost.ViewName#></h2>

<#
} else {
#>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title><#= mvcHost.ViewName #></title>
</head>
<body>
<#
    PushIndent("    ");
}
#>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
<#
List<ModelProperty> properties = GetModelProperties(mvcHost.ViewDataType);
foreach (ModelProperty property in properties) {
    if (!property.IsPrimaryKey && property.Scaffold) {
#>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.<#= property.ValueExpression #>)
        </th>
<#
    }
}
#>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
<#
foreach (ModelProperty property in properties) {
    if (!property.IsPrimaryKey && property.Scaffold) {
#>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => <#= property.ItemValueExpression #>)
        </td>
<#
    }
}

string pkName = GetPrimaryKeyName(mvcHost.ViewDataType);
if (pkName != null) {
#>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.<#= pkName #> }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.<#= pkName #> }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.<#= pkName #> })
        </td>
<#
} else {
#>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
<#
}
#>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<#
// The following code closes the asp:Content tag used in the case of a master page and the body and html tags in the case of a regular view page
#>
<#
if(mvcHost.IsContentPage) {
#>
<#
} else if(!mvcHost.IsPartialView && !mvcHost.IsContentPage) {
    ClearIndent();
#>
</body>
</html>
<#
}
#>
<#+
// Describes the information about a property on the model
class ModelProperty {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AssociationName { get; set; }
    public string ValueExpression { get; set; }
    public string ModelValueExpression { get; set; }
    public string ItemValueExpression { get; set; }
    public Type UnderlyingType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public bool IsForeignKey { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
    public bool Scaffold { get; set; }
}

// Change this list to include any non-primitive types you think should be eligible for display/edit
static Type[] bindableNonPrimitiveTypes = new[] {
    typeof(string),
    typeof(decimal),
    typeof(Guid),
    typeof(DateTime),
    typeof(DateTimeOffset),
    typeof(TimeSpan),
};

// Call this to get the list of properties in the model. Change this to modify or add your
// own default formatting for display values.
List<ModelProperty> GetModelProperties(Type type) {
    List<ModelProperty> results = GetEligibleProperties(type);
    
    foreach (ModelProperty prop in results) {
        if (prop.UnderlyingType == typeof(double) || prop.UnderlyingType == typeof(decimal)) {
            prop.ModelValueExpression = "String.Format(\"{0:F}\", " + prop.ModelValueExpression + ")";
        }
        else if (prop.UnderlyingType == typeof(DateTime)) {
            prop.ModelValueExpression = "String.Format(\"{0:g}\", " + prop.ModelValueExpression + ")";
        }
    }

    return results;
}

// Call this to determine if property has scaffolding enabled
bool Scaffold(PropertyInfo property) {
    foreach (object attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
        var scaffoldColumn = attribute as ScaffoldColumnAttribute;
        if (scaffoldColumn != null && !scaffoldColumn.Scaffold) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Call this to determine if the property represents a primary key. Change the
// code to change the definition of primary key.
bool IsPrimaryKey(PropertyInfo property) {
    if (string.Equals(property.Name, "id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {  // EF Code First convention
        return true;
    }

    if (string.Equals(property.Name, property.DeclaringType.Name + "id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {  // EF Code First convention
        return true;
    }

    foreach (object attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
        if (attribute is KeyAttribute) {  // WCF RIA Services and EF Code First explicit
            return true;
        }
        
        var edmScalar = attribute as EdmScalarPropertyAttribute;
        if (edmScalar != null && edmScalar.EntityKeyProperty) {  // EF traditional
            return true;
        }

        var column = attribute as ColumnAttribute;
        if (column != null && column.IsPrimaryKey) {  // LINQ to SQL
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

// This will return the primary key property name, if and only if there is exactly
// one primary key. Returns null if there is no PK, or the PK is composite.
string GetPrimaryKeyName(Type type) {
    IEnumerable<string> pkNames = GetPrimaryKeyNames(type);
    return pkNames.Count() == 1 ? pkNames.First() : null;
}

// This will return all the primary key names. Will return an empty list if there are none.
IEnumerable<string> GetPrimaryKeyNames(Type type) {
    return GetEligibleProperties(type).Where(mp => mp.IsPrimaryKey).Select(mp => mp.Name);
}

// Call this to determine if the property represents a foreign key.
bool IsForeignKey(PropertyInfo property) {
    return MvcTemplateHost.RelatedProperties.ContainsKey(property.Name);
}

// A foreign key, e.g. CategoryID, will have a value expression of Category.CategoryID
string GetValueExpressionSuffix(PropertyInfo property) {
    RelatedModel propertyModel;
    MvcTemplateHost.RelatedProperties.TryGetValue(property.Name, out propertyModel);

    return propertyModel != null ? propertyModel.PropertyName + "." + propertyModel.DisplayPropertyName : property.Name;
}

// A foreign key, e.g. CategoryID, will have an association name of Category
string GetAssociationName(PropertyInfo property) {
    RelatedModel propertyModel;
    MvcTemplateHost.RelatedProperties.TryGetValue(property.Name, out propertyModel);

    return propertyModel != null ? propertyModel.PropertyName : property.Name;
}

// Helper
List<ModelProperty> GetEligibleProperties(Type type) {
    List<ModelProperty> results = new List<ModelProperty>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
        Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
        if (prop.GetGetMethod() != null && prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && IsBindableType(underlyingType)) {
            string valueExpression = GetValueExpressionSuffix(prop);

            results.Add(new ModelProperty {
                Name = prop.Name,
                AssociationName = GetAssociationName(prop),
                ValueExpression = valueExpression,
                ModelValueExpression = "Model." + valueExpression,
                ItemValueExpression = "item." + valueExpression,
                UnderlyingType = underlyingType,
                IsPrimaryKey = IsPrimaryKey(prop),
                IsForeignKey = IsForeignKey(prop),
                IsReadOnly = prop.GetSetMethod() == null,
                Scaffold = Scaffold(prop)
            });
        }
    }

    return results;
}

// Helper
bool IsBindableType(Type type) {
    return type.IsPrimitive || bindableNonPrimitiveTypes.Contains(type);
}

MvcTextTemplateHost MvcTemplateHost {
    get {
        return (MvcTextTemplateHost)Host;
    }
}
#>
```

and this is new code:

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cshtml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Linq.Mapping" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Objects.DataClasses" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Scaffolding.BuiltIn" #>
<#
MvcTextTemplateHost mvcHost = MvcTemplateHost;
#>
@model IEnumerable<#= "<" + mvcHost.ViewDataTypeName + ">" #>
<#
// The following chained if-statement outputs the file header code and markup for a partial view, a content page, or a regular view.
if(mvcHost.IsPartialView) {
#>

<#
} else if(mvcHost.IsContentPage) {
#>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "<#= mvcHost.ViewName#>";
<#
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mvcHost.MasterPageFile)) {
#>
    Layout = "<#= mvcHost.MasterPageFile#>";
<#
}
#>
}

<h2>@ViewDate["Title"]</h2>

<#
} else {
#>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title><#= mvcHost.ViewName #></title>
</head>
<body>
<#
    PushIndent("    ");
}
#>
<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
  <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary me-md-2">Create New</a>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
<#
List<ModelProperty> properties = GetModelProperties(mvcHost.ViewDataType);
foreach (ModelProperty property in properties) {
    if (!property.IsPrimaryKey && property.Scaffold) {
#>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.<#= property.ValueExpression #>)
        </th>
<#
    }
}
#>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
<#
foreach (ModelProperty property in properties) {
    if (!property.IsPrimaryKey && property.Scaffold) {
#>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => <#= property.ItemValueExpression #>)
        </td>
<#
    }
}

string pkName = GetPrimaryKeyName(mvcHost.ViewDataType);
if (pkName != null) {
#>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-warning me-2" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.<#= pkName #>">Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info me-2" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.<#= pkName #>">Details</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger me-2" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.<#= pkName #>">Delete</a>
        </td>
<#
} else {
#>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-warning me-2" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="">Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-info me-2" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="">Details</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger me-2" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="">Delete</a>
        </td>
<#
}
#>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<#
// The following code closes the asp:Content tag used in the case of a master page and the body and html tags in the case of a regular view page
#>
<#
if(mvcHost.IsContentPage) {
#>
<#
} else if(!mvcHost.IsPartialView && !mvcHost.IsContentPage) {
    ClearIndent();
#>
</body>
</html>
<#
}
#>
<#+
// Describes the information about a property on the model
class ModelProperty {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AssociationName { get; set; }
    public string ValueExpression { get; set; }
    public string ModelValueExpression { get; set; }
    public string ItemValueExpression { get; set; }
    public Type UnderlyingType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public bool IsForeignKey { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
    public bool Scaffold { get; set; }
}

// Change this list to include any non-primitive types you think should be eligible for display/edit
static Type[] bindableNonPrimitiveTypes = new[] {
    typeof(string),
    typeof(decimal),
    typeof(Guid),
    typeof(DateTime),
    typeof(DateTimeOffset),
    typeof(TimeSpan),
};

// Call this to get the list of properties in the model. Change this to modify or add your
// own default formatting for display values.
List<ModelProperty> GetModelProperties(Type type) {
    List<ModelProperty> results = GetEligibleProperties(type);
    
    foreach (ModelProperty prop in results) {
        if (prop.UnderlyingType == typeof(double) || prop.UnderlyingType == typeof(decimal)) {
            prop.ModelValueExpression = "String.Format(\"{0:F}\", " + prop.ModelValueExpression + ")";
        }
        else if (prop.UnderlyingType == typeof(DateTime)) {
            prop.ModelValueExpression = "String.Format(\"{0:g}\", " + prop.ModelValueExpression + ")";
        }
    }

    return results;
}

// Call this to determine if property has scaffolding enabled
bool Scaffold(PropertyInfo property) {
    foreach (object attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
        var scaffoldColumn = attribute as ScaffoldColumnAttribute;
        if (scaffoldColumn != null && !scaffoldColumn.Scaffold) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Call this to determine if the property represents a primary key. Change the
// code to change the definition of primary key.
bool IsPrimaryKey(PropertyInfo property) {
    if (string.Equals(property.Name, "id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {  // EF Code First convention
        return true;
    }

    if (string.Equals(property.Name, property.DeclaringType.Name + "id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {  // EF Code First convention
        return true;
    }

    foreach (object attribute in property.GetCustomAttributes(true)) {
        if (attribute is KeyAttribute) {  // WCF RIA Services and EF Code First explicit
            return true;
        }
        
        var edmScalar = attribute as EdmScalarPropertyAttribute;
        if (edmScalar != null && edmScalar.EntityKeyProperty) {  // EF traditional
            return true;
        }

        var column = attribute as ColumnAttribute;
        if (column != null && column.IsPrimaryKey) {  // LINQ to SQL
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

// This will return the primary key property name, if and only if there is exactly
// one primary key. Returns null if there is no PK, or the PK is composite.
string GetPrimaryKeyName(Type type) {
    IEnumerable<string> pkNames = GetPrimaryKeyNames(type);
    return pkNames.Count() == 1 ? pkNames.First() : null;
}

// This will return all the primary key names. Will return an empty list if there are none.
IEnumerable<string> GetPrimaryKeyNames(Type type) {
    return GetEligibleProperties(type).Where(mp => mp.IsPrimaryKey).Select(mp => mp.Name);
}

// Call this to determine if the property represents a foreign key.
bool IsForeignKey(PropertyInfo property) {
    return MvcTemplateHost.RelatedProperties.ContainsKey(property.Name);
}

// A foreign key, e.g. CategoryID, will have a value expression of Category.CategoryID
string GetValueExpressionSuffix(PropertyInfo property) {
    RelatedModel propertyModel;
    MvcTemplateHost.RelatedProperties.TryGetValue(property.Name, out propertyModel);

    return propertyModel != null ? propertyModel.PropertyName + "." + propertyModel.DisplayPropertyName : property.Name;
}

// A foreign key, e.g. CategoryID, will have an association name of Category
string GetAssociationName(PropertyInfo property) {
    RelatedModel propertyModel;
    MvcTemplateHost.RelatedProperties.TryGetValue(property.Name, out propertyModel);

    return propertyModel != null ? propertyModel.PropertyName : property.Name;
}

// Helper
List<ModelProperty> GetEligibleProperties(Type type) {
    List<ModelProperty> results = new List<ModelProperty>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
        Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
        if (prop.GetGetMethod() != null && prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && IsBindableType(underlyingType)) {
            string valueExpression = GetValueExpressionSuffix(prop);

            results.Add(new ModelProperty {
                Name = prop.Name,
                AssociationName = GetAssociationName(prop),
                ValueExpression = valueExpression,
                ModelValueExpression = "Model." + valueExpression,
                ItemValueExpression = "item." + valueExpression,
                UnderlyingType = underlyingType,
                IsPrimaryKey = IsPrimaryKey(prop),
                IsForeignKey = IsForeignKey(prop),
                IsReadOnly = prop.GetSetMethod() == null,
                Scaffold = Scaffold(prop)
            });
        }
    }

    return results;
}

// Helper
bool IsBindableType(Type type) {
    return type.IsPrimitive || bindableNonPrimitiveTypes.Contains(type);
}

MvcTextTemplateHost MvcTemplateHost {
    get {
        return (MvcTextTemplateHost)Host;
    }
}
#>
```

after finished and restart visual studio 2022 not the new list does not work when add view for action

search on any related article to resolve this issue.

these instructions follow:

Here are the steps to regenerate an edited T4 template:

1. **Make Your Edits**: Open the **`List.tt`** file from the specified path (**`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML`**) in a text editor or an integrated development environment like Visual Studio.
2. **Edit the Template**: Modify the content of the **`List.tt`** file as needed to make your desired changes.
3. **Save Your Changes**: Save the **`List.tt`** file after making your edits.
4. **Open Visual Studio**: Open or restart Visual Studio.
5. **Create a New View**: In your ASP.NET Core project, create a new view or regenerate an existing view that should use the modified template. Right-click on the folder where you want to create the view (e.g., in the Views folder), select "Add," and then choose "View."
6. **Configure View Options**: In the "Add View" dialog, configure the options for your view. Make sure you choose the appropriate template that corresponds to the **`List.tt`** template you edited.
7. **Regenerate the Code**: Click the "Add" button in the "Add View" dialog to regenerate the view. Visual Studio will apply your changes to the **`List.tt`** template and generate the code accordingly.